# Bootstrap - column ordering/mixing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to do something like this in bootstrap?

[image]

From md size to xs size i want to change ordering of my columns. 2 rows are not important if its needed.

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

`Col-sm-12` ensures the div is full width on small screen. `xs: extra small, md: medium` and `lg: large`. The number is like a ratio. The maximum width is 12, 6 is half the width and col: column obviously. you could have used two `rows` to do so but I personally prefer the column in cases like this for no special reason.

For example if you wanted the div to take 1/3th of the div on small screen you would use `col-sm-4` since 4 * 3 = 12.

### [Read the documentation here - Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

---

Solution to your problem is here:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6">color red</div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 hidden-xs">color blue</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">yellow</div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-6">orange</div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 visible-xs hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg">color blue</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I know exacly how its work. But if you look on picture u will see its different order in xs than your answer. With your solution my `col2` will be second in `xs` but i want it to be last.

Comment: @sko i added the hidden in 'col2' and another column that appears only on xtra small screens